# Constraints and SubLayers(CALayer) not updating

Tags: ios

I have created a left border in a superView

```
...
    var leftLayer: CALayer?
    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.leftLayer = CALayer()
        self.leftLayer?.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.leftLayer?.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.leftLayer!)
...
```

and then in layoutSubviews I try to update the border acording to constraints:

```
...
override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        leftLayer!.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: 0,
                                  width: 1,
                                  height: self.frame.size.height)

}
...
```

But sub CALayers is not following the top CALayer/UIViews constraints . I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111099/calayer-not-resizing-with-autolayout), but unable to add layers to a superview.

Do you know how to have a sub CALayer follow the constraints of the containing UIView?

Comment: If you are overriding a UIKIt method is always better to call `super`

Comment: You are "super" right :-) But it does unfortunately not solve the problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the view's frame property to adjust its sub layers frame:

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet{
        leftLayer!.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: 0,
                                  width: 1,
                                  height: self.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```